# How can I solve type is not assignable error

Tags: angular, typescript, api, service, angular-material

**Please check the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75973021/12540455) ,the solution does solve the problem but creates an error in fake service implemented in games.service.fake.ts .There is a type mismatch error but when adding the type from the answer it shows unknown property error**
You can find the exact error on [games.service.fake.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-conlc3?file=src/app/games/games.service.fake.ts) and [games-chart.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-conlc3?file=src/app/games-chart/games-chart.component.spec.ts).

Comment: Please put a [mre] in _this_ question.